# related to C# & procedure

Tags: asp.net

i have created a huge web form and want to create and call procedure for it.the C# .net form is in visual studio and procedure from SQL plus. kindly help me create and call procedure for such huge web form, as it has multiple questions.

Here is my code from **.aspx.cs**

```
public void insert_pageA(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dsn1"].ConnectionString;
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "FILL_FORM";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try                                                   
    {

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_NAME", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox53.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_ADD_NAME", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = txtAddName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_1", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = txtLastAdd.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_2", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_3", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_4", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_5", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_6", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_7", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_8", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox7.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_10", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox9.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_11", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox10.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_12", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox11.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_13", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox12.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_14", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox13.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_15", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox14.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_16", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox15.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_17", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox16.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_18", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox17.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_19", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox18.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_20", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox19.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_QUESTION_21", OracleType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox20.Text;

}
}
```

procedure:

Create or replace procedure fill_form ( question_id in number, Answer_text in varchar2, Answer_boolean in number ) 
as 
Begin Insert into vendor_question_d(question_id,answer_text,answer_boolean) Values(question_id,answer_text,answer_boolean); 
Commit; 
End;

Comment: please if you could help me creating and calling procedure in sql plus @chirag

Comment: is it giving any error.?

Comment: yes its not able to pass arguments to procedure @Chirag

Comment: try passing `ParameterDirection.Input` to your `Parameters.Add()` method.
So your final code should look like `cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("AN_NAME", OracleType.VarChar,ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = TextBox53.Text;`

Comment: SQL> desc fill_form
PROCEDURE fill_form
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 QUESTION_ID                    NUMBER                  IN
 ANSWER_TEXT                    VARCHAR2                IN
 ANSWER_BOOLEAN                 NUMBER                  IN                             this is the procedure created @chirag

Comment: got error of invalid arguments. but the main problem is calling it to procedure. as shown above is the procedure created (which m doubted of and the calling is giving error @chirag

Comment: If possible, Include your SP in question.

Comment: stored procedure is it?? it given in the above box @chirag

Comment: Create or replace procedure fill_form
( question_id in number,
Answer_text in varchar2,
Answer_boolean in number
) as
Begin
Insert into vendor_question_d(question_id,answer_text,answer_boolean)
Values(question_id,answer_text,answer_boolean);
Commit;
End;
 @chirag

Comment: and after calling it is showing this error:     ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ACCOUNTS"."VENDOR_QUESTION_ANSWER_D"."ANSWER_SRNO")
ORA-06512: at "ACCOUNTS.FILL_FORM", line 8               @Chirag